# Returning User Roles to an AngularJS app from ASP.NET Identity using OAuth and bearer tokens

Tags: security, angularjs, asp.net-identity

I'm implementing an AngularJS SPA with a backend implemented as a WebAPI seeded from a Visual Studio 2013 template. AngularJS does everything including login and I've successfully got it submitting to //localhost/token and received back a token which I add to subsequent request headers. However, I now want to make decisions on what AngularJS templates to render based on the users role(s) and therefore I need the role(s) client-side (I'm securing all my server code by role so having these decisions made client-side is fine.)

To that end I'm thinking of adding something along the lines of this...

```
foreach (var claim in context.Identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type.EndsWith("/role")))
{
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("role", claim.Value);
}
```

... to the ApplicationOAuthProvider.TokenEndpoint() method so that the role(s) are added to the JSON that's returned back to the AngularJS code when the token is fetched.

I realise the code above doesn't work for more that one role at the moment but I'm more interested in knowing if this is the correct way to access role information and whether I'm adding it in the correct fashion?

Answer (score 1):

ng-conf happened a few days ago and a nicely thought out solution was presented. Here is the link to the [video](http://youtu.be/62RvRQuMVyg?t=2m34s). He talks about authorization for ~10 minutes.

Basically it involves providing an activeUser service to your app and then conditionally loading directives based on features described in that service.

As for getting roles...

```
var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
// or if not async
var userRoles = UserManager.GetRoles(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

**update**

Since your conclusion, I might suggest something like this:

-[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongyes/archive/2012/03/12/using-razor-template-engine-in-web-api-self-host-application.aspx)-

It is basically the solution spoken about at ng-conf but it's rendered inside a web-api controller. Forgoing the need for MVC all together.

What the model contains or even what index.cshtml is rendered depends upon whatever logic you use for determining whether a user is authenticated and authorized for.

Comment: Thanks. I love the idea presented at the ng-conf. It's left me wondering how to take my app forward. I took an ASP.NET MVC template with WebAPI too but ripped out the MVC login pages leaving me with something that delivered static AngularJS content. I think I have the choice now of going back to the MVC login pages or performing a window.location change after the AngularJS in order to reconstruct index.HTML with the Active Profile. I prefer the latter.

Comment: That would work, but it might not be worth keeping MVC around. I've updated my answer with a different solution